# GetBufferLock timed out for thread

Tags: android, debugging

I am developing on Android Samsung galaxy TAB 10.1. After I official updated to 4.0.4 version often get error:

```
11-01 17:04:35.382: E/gralloc(11657): GetBufferLock timed out for thread 11657 buffer 0x55 usage 0x33 LockState 1
```

and device immediate restarts. This error appear totally random and if I am debugging my own applications.

Any suggestion?

P.S.

My only one infinite paint loop:

```
public void run() {
    Canvas canvas = null;

    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            synchronized (lock) {
                if (!invalidated)
                    continue;
            }

            canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();

            synchronized (mHolder) {
                onDraw(canvas);
            }

            synchronized (lock) {
                invalidated = false;
            }
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                canvas = null;
            }
        }

        synchronized (lock) {
            if (painter == null)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you use  a custom rom or an alternative android system, or the regular one from samsung?  Also, what are you doing on the tablet when it crash ?

Comment: I am using regular one from samsung. Only one thing what I see, crash only my debuggable applications.

Comment: you mean it crashes only when running your application ? are you doing some heavy display ?

Comment: Crash whole device. Device put this message into logcat and device just restarts.

Answer (score 1):

I guess something is wrong this the GPU memory,  are you doing some heavy graphic display when this error occurs ?

if not... maybe another app is.

It's worth checking for app with heavy GPU consumption ( Probably an heavy live wallpaper ? ) and remove it. then a reboot should fix this.

also just be aware that you should never ever write :

```
while (true) {
}
```

at least add a running flag :

```
while(running){
}
```

so you can set running to false on application stop.

Comment: My application doesn't do anything special with graphics, just regular view repainting. Wallpaper is static, no widgets. Could you tell how  I can determine GPU memory problems?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a block which needed to be accessed by other thread is used by infinitely by your application. Are you running infinite loop inside your paint method ?

Comment: I added my only one infinite loop. But application is crashing in activities, where I am not using custom views. I am tottaly sure only one thread repainting in this surface holder. I added my code to question for you.